# jest: unable to mock methods/hooks using `jest.spyOn`

Tags: javascript, next.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm trying to mock the methods & hooks in a file and import those mock functions as I need them, in my test files.

`useMyHook.jsx`

```js
const useMyHook = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(200)

  return { val }
}

export { useMyHook }
```

`Hello.jsx`:

```js
import { useTestHook } from "@/hooks/useTestHook";

export const Hello = () => {
  const { val } = useTestHook();
  console.log({ val });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is the file where i mock the hooks & functions.
`mock-hooks.js`:

```js
import { useMyHook } from "@/hooks/useMyHook";
// import * as Hook from "@/hooks/useMyHook";

const mocks = {
  useMyHook: (val = 9999) => {
    jest
      .spyOn({ useMyHook }, "useMyHook")
      .mockImplementation(() => ({ val }));

    /** this method of mocking used to work before, but now it gives 
        `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useMyHook` */
    // jest.spyOn(Hook, "useMyHook")
    //   .mockImplementation(() => ({ val }));

  },
};

export { mocks };
```

the `useMyHook` hook is a bare minimum hook which just returns a value(state).

i'm importing the `mocks` variable in my test file and calling `mocks.useMyHook()`, but it doesn't work. I still get the original hook's value in return while testing.

I'm testing a `Hello.jsx` component which uses `useMyHook` hooks and **logs its return value in console**.

`Hello.test.jsx`:

```js
import { mocks } from "@/utils/test/mock-hooks";

import { Hello } from "./Hello";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("Hello test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mocks.useMyHook(12345);
    render(<Hello />, {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => <>{children}</>,
    });
  });

  test("should render the main container", () => {
    screen.debug()
  });
});
```

when i run the test, I still see the original hook's value being logged in console, instead of the mock value(12345).

I found out that using `jest.mock` before the `describe` instead of `jest.spyOn` works.
But I have a lot of tests that **change the mocked value during the tests**(like **inside a specific `test()` block**) by calling `mocks.useMyHook` and the hook would return another value for that specific test cases.
The `spyOn` method used to work previously fine, but alot of things changed in the project so now I'm unable to make it work.

I'm on a next js project.
Here's some info on the project:

dependencies:

```json
{
  ...
 "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.17.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "27.4.6",
    "jest": "28.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.0"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({});

const customJestConfig = {
  collectCoverageFrom: ["**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  verbose: true,
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/"],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.next"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/.next/"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": ["babel-jest", { presets: ["next/babel"] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$",
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
  },
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

`.babelrc`:

```json
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

EDIT: Typo & Added `useMyHook` hook & `Hello` component code.

Comment: You're spying on the property of an object that _only exists_ to have its property spied on, and is accessible from anywhere else (tests or otherwise).

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry i dont understand what you're implying here.
the `useMyHook` file has a react hook defined like `const useMyHook = () => { ... }` and exported as `export { useMyHook }` in that file.
I'm just expecting that hook to be mocked by jest.

Comment: `jest.spyOn({ useMyHook }, "useMyHook").mockImplementation(() => ({ val }));` creates an object and spies on it, but that object has _no connection_ to anything else happening in your program or its tests.

Comment: once i do `jest.spyOn` like that, won't that mock the hook to return the mocked value, anywhere that it is used?
i've added the component and the hooks code as well in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just updating the `jest.config.js`'s transform property solved the issue.

```
transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mjs)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }]
  },
```

i needed to add `mjs` as well, to the transform patterns.

Hope this helps someone.